# Installing Xdebug in Eclipse on Mac

Tags: php, eclipse, macos, xdebug

I am struggling all day long to get Xdebug working on Eclipse Helios for php on my Mac. I have rewritten my php.ini file which is located at /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/conf/php.ini as follows;

```
zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-     20121212/xdebug.so" 
xdebug.remote_enable = On
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode = req
xdebug.remote_host = localhost
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.idekey =
xdebug.profiler_enable = On
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = “/Applications/MAMP/tmp/xdebug/”
```

Also, I have Komodo-PHPRemoteDubgging and replaced xdebug.so file in /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/xdebug.so

If I look into phpInfo() I can find the term Xdebug.

Still, when I try to run my web app on eclipse at debug mode, it stops at 57%.

Can somebody help me out on this?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I got the answer to my own question. I have replaced the contents under [xdebug] in the php.ini file with the below contents;

[xdebug]

```
zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.5.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=On
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_autostart=Off
xdebug.profiler_enable = On
xdebug.profiler_dir = “/Applications/MAMP/tmp”
xdebug.collect_vars=on
xdebug.collect_params=4
xdebug.dump_globals=on
xdebug.dump.GET=*
xdebug.dump.POST=*
xdebug.show_local_vars=on
```

I have no idea what the difference is, but now it finally seems to work.